# Mysql where clause syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, where-clause

I was running through some of our code at work and came across this structure for an sql query and was sure it was a typo in the variables of our PHP, I ran it and it works.

```
Select column from table where value = column;
```

Anyone I know was always taught the correct syntax is:

```
Select column from table where column = value;
```

Is there any reason for this being legal, other than SQL just checks are both sides of an equation equal to each other?
I'm more posting this because I found it really interesting, like a 'the more you know' kind of thing.

Comment: There are some good answers below, but I want to add a possible perspective as to why that syntax was chosen. I have personally started to adopt syntax of `if (value == $var)` in php so that if I accidentally miss the second `=` it will throw a syntax error rather than assigning value when I intended to do a comparison and having a runtime error that may go unnoticed. It doesn't necessarily apply to SQL, it will work fine either way, but I at least like it for other stuff.

Comment: You make a really great point, consider me a convert! Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality operator (`=`) is symmetric - if `a=b` is true, then so is `b=a`. `a` and `b` can be column names, values or complex expressions. It's common to use the form `column=value`, but syntactically speaking, it's completely equivalent to `value=column`.

Comment: Why is it that we can't compare tuples in this case? "where 1,2 = 1,2" where it would be treated as a short hand for "where 1=1 and 2=2"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have it right sql just checks both sides of an equation. The equation could even contain a column on *neither* side! such as

```
SELECT column from table where 1=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of an SQL query is :

```
SELECT what_to_select
FROM which_table
WHERE conditions_to_satisfy;
```

You can use any condition you want, for example :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1
```

will return you all the rows

while

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0
```

will return you nothing

after a WHERE you must have a condition, nothing else